# why it is always showing output as 1?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def power(x,n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return power(x * x, n % 2)
    else:
        return x * power(x, n - 1)
print power(2,3)
```

What ever the input I give it is showing either 1 or 2. can anybody please help me where I went wrong. I am newbie to programming. Thank you

Comment: Please first correct the indentation of your code

Comment: I've always found those kind of comments silly and very unwelcoming. The indentation is probably perfectly fine in the code.

Comment: What do you want the code to do?

Comment: One comment. This is kind of creepy implementation of power() function. you can save pow(x,y/2) in temp and use it to avoid multiple callings

Comment: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-calculate-powxn/ see this for better detail

Comment: @jester112358 : we don't _know_ wether the indentation is ok in the real code (and it happened to be the culprit in more than one "why doesn't my code work" post here), and _we_ need to have correctly indented code to answer any question anyway - remember that in Python, indentation is not cosmetic.

Comment: @bruno He would get an indentation error if there were issues. He said that he just gets a wrong result.

Comment: The code has to print x^n  @Rob

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I am not getting any error. code works fine. Problem is with output. I didn't post this code any where. Today I am working on  it and couldn't sort out the problem so seeking help.

Comment: @jester112358 issues in indentation can yield syntactically valid yet logically invalid code - but that's not the point: the point is that in Python indentation is part of the language so you have to post correctly indented code, period.

Comment: @bruno I think you're underlining the atmosphere here that I tried to comment in the first place. Have a nice periods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
return power(x * x, n % 2)
```

to this:

```
return power(x * x, n / 2)
```

if n is divisible by 2, you are calculating `pow(x * x, 0)` which will always return 1.

Comment: No problem! Try something like `print "x: %s n: %s" % (x, n) in the first line of the function to help diagnose these types of issues. Or maybe a print inside each branch of the if statement. Then you can walk through examples and see why it doesn't match what you would expect.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion @camz. I will sure try this :) :)